# Need to divide single column into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

My table has data with a single column:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And I want output like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5-first row
6 7 8 9 10 - second row
```

Another has two columns like this:

```
Column 1           Column 2
1                  a
2                  b
3                  c
4                  d
5                  e
6                  f
7                  g
8                  h
9                  i
10                 j
```

And I want it to display like this:

```
1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e-first row
6 f 7 g 8 h 9 i 10 j - second row
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first case you can use `ROW_NUMBER` then `PIVOT` to do this using the [modulo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) operator to divide into columns and the result of integer divsion by 5 to group into rows.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT C,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C) -1)%5 AS Col,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C) -1)/5 AS Row
FROM YourTable       
)
SELECT [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM CTE
PIVOT (MAX(C) FOR Col IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])) AS Pvt
ORDER BY Row
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06abe/1)

For the second case Oracle has a [straight forward syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11988486/73226) to achieve this with `PIVOT`. SQL Server doesn't but you can do this as below.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1) -1)%5 AS Col,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1) -1)/5 AS Row
FROM YourTable       
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 0 THEN Column1 END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 0 THEN Column2 END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 1 THEN Column1 END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 1 THEN Column2 END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 2 THEN Column1 END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 2 THEN Column2 END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 3 THEN Column1 END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 3 THEN Column2 END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 4 THEN Column1 END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 4 THEN Column2 END)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Row
ORDER BY Row
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/253d7/3)

Comment: If its have two column means how to perform this opertaion?

Comment: @SureshSurya - Please edit your question to include example data and desired results for this case.

Comment: @MartinSmith Great answer, I would replace the pseudo `SELECT *` with `SELECT Column1, Column2` for the sake of good habit... :)

Comment: @Justicator - I used to do that but now I'm more relaxed about `*` in places where it does not make any difference. In the first query in my answer it would make a difference as any new columns added to `YourTable` would silently be added to the implicitly defined `GROUP BY` of the `PIVOT` likely causing the query to return incorrect results. In the second case even if a new column was added SQL Server wouldn't unnecessarily retrieve it. It recognises at compile time that only `Column1` and `Column2` would be used.

Comment: @MartinSmith You are correct of course, But... I work with programmers and find it easier to "force" them to _always_ use column names than to make them _think_ before and decide each time. I also think that not everyone who reads an answer here understands when it makes no difference and why (well, now they know...), therefor it was just "for the sake of good habit". This is definitely not to lessen from your really great answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith sometimes this select shows null in between columns....why?

Comment: @SureshE - If the number of values is not evenly divisible by 5 then the last row will have `NULL`s to pad out the missing value. If the source data has `NULL`s these will appear in the results. If neither of those explain it please provide more details.

Comment: thanks for the information.....and its working good and all null values in the end only.....